# Titanium Windows Phone: How can i save a file in visible folders?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm developing a windows phone application built with Titanium SDK 5.2.2.

I'm not able to save a file in directories directly accessible by the device (like Downloads directory).

I tried to use the only supported functionalities of Titanium API *Titanium.Filesystem.getFile* and *Titanium.Filesystem.File.write*, but the only way to save the file is to use *Ti.FileSystem.applicationDataDirectory* or *Ti.File.resourcesDirectory* to decide the path where store it.

It seems that, using these API, I cannot store file in one of the directories visible by the device(Documents, Downloads, Photos, Music), and then make them available inside the device.

Can I perform this download in the path visible to the device such as Downloads folder?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the `externalStorageDirectory` location:
https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile_windows/blob/e3ecddfe13179509e3b8d0699141763262ef5a97/Source/Filesystem/src/Filesystem.cpp#L81

We've had a similar request to expose the Downloads/Documents folder for iOS. I'd suggest to add a comment to request parity for Windows or create a new ticket:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23197

Comment: I tried to use externalStorageDirectory in the following script:  
`var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory, 'file.txt'); alert(f.nativePath); f.write("blablablabla");`  Nothing seems to be created in the accessible directories of the SDcard.  The alert prints the following url: "C:\data\Programs\WindowsApps\projectIdFolder_1.0.0.0_x86__r44nfdsyzca2j\file.txt‌​‌​".  I tried also the Ti.Filesystem.applicationSupportDirectory and Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory but with the same results.

Comment: OK, that sucks. Could you check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, please create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Answer (score 0):

I opened an issue on Appcelerator JIRA for this question:

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-3615 .